# Connect-PnPonline using certificate

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a azure release  pipeline. In order for that to work I have made app registration and created certificate. The method I am using to connect right now is as following:
`Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sharepointside -ClientId $id -Tenant $Tenant -CertificateBase64Encoded $encoded -CertificatePassword $password`

I went this method because this way I don't have to upload the certificate to my azure devops. But I have some concern about storing the certificate password in the variable. Is there way I can connect to sharepoint from azure pipeline without using password variable? Or any idea on other options I can use?

Comment: If you are asking for a safe place to store the password, why not add it as a secret in a azure key vault? Easy to retrive using PowerShell, but will take some extra steps/time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,@christoffer. I have now created azure key vault but I am having trouble getting the variable value when using powershell type FilePath. It works fine with powershell type Inline. Any suggestion? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300600/azure-key-vault-secret-value-coming-up-as-null-when-using-powershell-type-filepa

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest you 2 ideas.

First, the easiest, you can use the `Get-PnPStoredCredential` command which you need to use the Windows Credential Manager in Control Panel safely.

```
$cred = Get-PnPStoredCredential -Name myCredential
#supply the $cred.Password to the command
```

Secondly, you can use the command that I have used a lot, convert from and to SecureString. But it's also best to keep the current Windows account password safe, as it'll be encrypted with the current username as the key.

```
$ssPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString
#Then type your password
$ss = ConvertFrom-SecureString $ssPassword
Set-Content -Path ".\password.pwd" -Value $ss
```

Then you can store the `$ss` in a text file. To use it, see below.

```
$ssPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString (Get-Content -Path ".\password.pwd")
#supply the $ssPassword to the command
```

That's all. Hope it helps.